# Mass Updating Single Database in MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

EDIT 2: After looking through other questions and the advice from you lovely people here, I've found the answer, and the program works awesome now! Thanks guys!

EDIT: I have updated my code based on the suggestions of other users here. Seriously, you guys are so awesome!

I have a page that works on my localhost, but not on my Dev/Test servers.

Here is how the page works:

1. User uploads xml file and posts.
2. Program parses through Xml file to create a list of BoxViewModels.
3. The program deletes all of the boxes in the Boxes table using a
   function-import called DeleteAllBoxes. All this function import does is execute "DELETE FROM dbo.Boxes;"
4. Using the list of BoxViewModels, the program updates the database
   with all of the boxes.

This works perfectly on my localhost (I have verified that all 312 boxes are successfully entered into the boxes table), but when I try it on my Dev/Test server using the same file, the only thing that happens is that all of the boxes are deleted. Furthermore, it takes about a minute or two before the program on my localhost finishes, but only a few seconds for the program on Dev/Test to finish. I would have expected Dev/Test to take at least as long as my localhost. I don't think it's a file size issue, because the file size is only 112Kb. It's like the foreach loop with the boxesList doesn't have any boxes, or is ignored entirely.

Here is my code in case it helps. I think that the solution is likely a setting I need to set in the web.config, but I could be wrong about something in my thinking too.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase fileFromPage)
    {
        if (fileFromPage != null) //User must upload a file.
        {
            if (fileFromPage.ContentType == "text/xml") //File must be an xml file.
            {
                List<BoxViewModel> boxesList = new List<BoxViewModel>();

                try //No errors will be caught if all boxes in the xml file are valid.
                {

                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(fileFromPage.InputStream);

                    XmlNodeList boxNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/initialize/boxes/box");

                    //Write each box in the xml to a BoxViewModel, then add to the boxesList for updating the database later.
                    foreach (XmlNode boxNode in boxNodeList)
                    {
                        XmlNode currentBoxNode = boxNode;
                        BoxViewModel currentBox = new BoxViewModel();

                        currentBox.Compliment = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("compliment").InnerText;
                        currentBox.Description = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText;
                        currentBox.BoxType = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("boxtype").InnerText;
                        currentBox.InsideLength = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("il").InnerText);
                        currentBox.InsideBreadth = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ib").InnerText);
                        currentBox.InsideHeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ih").InnerText);
                        currentBox.OutsideLength = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ol").InnerText);
                        currentBox.OutsideBreadth = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ob").InnerText);
                        currentBox.OutsideHeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("oh").InnerText);
                        currentBox.BoxWeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("bw").InnerText);
                        currentBox.BoxGrossWeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("bgw").InnerText);
                        currentBox.BoxStrength = int.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("boxstrength").InnerText);

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentBox.Compliment))
                            throw new Exception();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentBox.Description))
                            throw new Exception();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentBox.BoxType))
                            throw new Exception();

                        boxesList.Add(currentBox);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    ViewBag.MsgText = "There was an error when processing the file!";
                    ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
                }

                try
                {
                    if (boxesList.Count > 0) //Only update if there is at least one box.
                    {
                        dbEntities.DeleteAllBoxes(); //Clear the Boxes table for the new boxes.

                        foreach (BoxViewModel box in boxesList) //For each box in the boxesList, add a new box to the database.
                        {
                            Box newBox = new Box()
                            {
                                BoxGrossWeight = box.BoxGrossWeight,
                                //BoxID = model.BoxID,
                                BoxStrength = box.BoxStrength,
                                BoxType = box.BoxType,
                                BoxWeight = box.BoxWeight,
                                Compliment = box.Compliment,
                                Description = box.Description,
                                InsideBreadth = box.InsideBreadth,
                                InsideHeight = box.InsideHeight,
                                InsideLength = box.InsideLength,
                                OutsideBreadth = box.OutsideBreadth,
                                OutsideHeight = box.OutsideHeight,
                                OutsideLength = box.OutsideLength,
                                UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now
                            };

                            dbEntities.Boxes.AddObject(newBox);
                        }

                        //Save changes then redirect to page where user can see the results of the upload.
                        dbEntities.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.MsgText = "There are no boxes in this file!";
                        ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
                        return View();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    ViewBag.MsgText = "There was an error while updating the database!";
                    ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.MsgText = "The file must be an xml file!";
                ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.MsgText = "You must attach a file!";
            ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Please help! :(

Comment: Do you get redirected to index or get sent to whatever the view is associated with the other return?

Comment: On both my localhost and Dev/Test, I am redirected to the Index whenever the file is "successful." On localhost, this means the user can see the boxes. On Dev/Test, it's just a blank grid because the new boxes don't appear to be added.
With the return at the bottom of the page, the user is returned to the FileUpload page, which is the page that isn't working properly on Dev/Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the path to your file in the post not the contents of the file. So locally it says load c:\temp\whatever.xml and can find it but on the server that file doesn't exist. So you hit the first catch block, it recovers deletes all of the boxes then returns successfully. I'd put a `return View();` inside that catch block to be certain.

Comment: Oh ok! So it's looking for a file on the actual server that doesn't exist on that server! I'll try that right now!

Comment: You were right! The program says there aren't any boxes in that file. Knowing this, how do I make it so that the user can upload a file from their own machine? I'll update my code shortly.

Comment: Ok, so now I know the stakes. I need to figure out how to get the contents of the file and use the LoadXml method. I can mark this as the answer if you come up with how to do that first. If I figure out how to do it, I'll still mark this as the answer and then update my code to explain how I did it.

Comment: I changed xmlDoc.Load(fileFromPage.FileName); to xmlDoc.Load(fileFromPage.InputStream); and it works! Thanks for catching that for me!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if this should be "update" (by delete and insert new set), be sure to make delete and inserts in the single transaction - so either it complete whole, or nothing changes . In Entity Framework you do this simply by calling `SaveChanges` one time, after all the statements modifing entities. Or you can use `TransactionScope` explicitely.

As for the problem with entities not being inserted, there are no way to tell from your code - it seems fine to me from quick review. Try some logging - for example log number of entities in modified state from your `DbContext` just before `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Ok, so I'll save the changes right before returning the Redirect to Index. I was thinking every time that you made a change, it was required that the changes be saved, or else the database wouldn't remember it when you changed something else. I was wrong then and that's good news for me!